# Compare two lists and add missing items by specific criteria

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, compare

I have written a code like below:

```
foreach (var itemA in itm)
{
    foreach (var itemB in filteredList)
    {
        if (itemA.ItemID != itemB.ItemID)
        {
            missingList.Add(itemB);
            ListToUpdate.Add(itemB);
        }
        else
        {
            if (itemA.QuantitySold != itemB.QuantitySold)
            {
                ListToUpdate.Add(itemB);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see i have two lists here which are identical in their structure and they are:

```
List #1 is "itm" list - which contains old records from DB

List #2 is "filteredList" - which has all items from DB and + new ones
```

I'm trying to add items to missingList and ListToUpdate on next criteria:

```
All items that are "new" in filteredList - meaning their ItemID doens't exists in  "itm" list should be added to missingList.

And all items that are new in filteredList- filteredList - meaning their ItemID doens't exists in  "itm" list should be added to .ListToUpdate

And final criteria to add items to ListToUpdate should be those items that exist in both lists - and if the quantitysold in "itm" list is different - add them to ListToUpdate
```

The code above that I written gives me completely wrong results, I end up having more than 50000 items extra in both lists...

I'd like to change this code in a manner that it works like I wrote above and to possibly use parallel loops or PLINQ to speed things up...

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: In short, you have two lists, create a new list for the IDs which are present only in Filtered List and create another list for IDs which are present in both the lists(ListToUpdate) . Is that right?

Comment: You should write one method for each of the criteria to receive the 3 subsets of the problem and then combine the results. Bonus: the 3 methods can run parrallel.

Comment: @Anand Yes that's correct, with a little change  for 2nd list -create another list for IDs which are present in both the lists(ListToUpdate) but only those who have different QuantitySold property, meaning an ItemID from new list has more Quantity sold than the ItemID from old list (db)

Comment: @Dawnkeeper Could you show me an example on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx), which is available in C# 4.0:

```
    Parallel.ForEach(filteredList, (f) =>
    {
        var conditionMatchCount = itm.AsParallel().Max(i =>
        // One point if ID matches
        ((i.ItemID == f.ItemID) ? 1 : 0) +
        // One point if ID and QuantitySold match
        ((i.ItemID == f.ItemID && i.QuantitySold == f.QuantitySold) ? 1 : 0)
        );

        // Item is missing
        if (conditionMatchCount == 0)
        {
            listToUpdate.Add(f);
            missingList.Add(f);
        }
        // Item quantity is different
        else if (conditionMatchCount == 1)
        {
            listToUpdate.Add(f);
        }
    });
```

The above code uses two nested parallelised list iterators.

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example to compare two lists which will give you list of new IDs.

Class I used to hold the data

```
 public class ItemList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Function to get new IDs

```
private static void GetNewIdList()
    {
        List<ItemList> lstItm = new List<ItemList>();
        List<ItemList> lstFiltered = new List<ItemList>();

        ItemList oItemList = new ItemList();
        oItemList.ID = 1;
        lstItm.Add(oItemList);
        lstFiltered.Add(oItemList);

        oItemList = new ItemList();
        oItemList.ID = 2;
        lstItm.Add(oItemList);
        lstFiltered.Add(oItemList);

        oItemList = new ItemList();
        oItemList.ID = 3;
        lstFiltered.Add(oItemList);

        var lstListToUpdate = lstFiltered.Except(lstItm);


        Console.WriteLine(lstListToUpdate);
    }
```

For getting the list of common IDs use following

```
  var CommonList = from p in lstItm
                         join q in lstFiltered
                         on p.ID equals q.ID
                         select p;
```

**UPDATE 2**
For getting the list of new IDs from filtered list based on ID

```
 var lstListToUpdate2 = lstFiltered.Where(a => !lstItm.Select(b => b.ID).Contains(a.ID));
```

Comment: based on which criteria does the Except method compares the two lists ? Since my class type is the one generated from EF, i should probably override except method so that I could compare 2 lists on specific property?

Comment: I have pasted the updates in the code above for specifying the attribute.